# Given a polynomial, can we construct an orthogonal sequence?

Tags: polynomials, orthogonal-polynomials

Suppose we are given a polynomial $p(x)$ of degree $k$ which has all of its (distinct) roots in $[-1, 1]$. Is there is any way, generally, to choose a non-negative weight function $w(x)$ such that $\int_{-1}^{1} p(x) q(x) w(x) dx = 0$ for all $q$ with $\deg(q) < k$?

Comment: 1/ Orthogonal with respect to what inner product? 2/ There's an infinity of polynomials orthogonal to $p(x)$, so there will be an infinity of choices. Of course, once you have picked a complete set, there will be no possibility to expand it further, but you could start anew with a different choice and obtain another complete set.

Comment: 1/ Any inner product, when I say "construct" I mean choosing polynomials in the sequence other than $p_k$ (which must be equal to $p$) and a weight function defining the inner product. 2/ Of course, there will be an infinity of choices of polynomials orthogonal to $p(x)$, but in the sequence, we must also have $\text{deg}(p_j) = j$. I'm pretty sure there exist sequences of polynomials that are not orthogonal with respect to any weight function/inner product.

Comment: It is a fact that orthogonal polynomial sequences must satisfy a three-term recurrence relation of the form outlined in the linked Wikipedia article, so a sequence not satisfying this, for instance, will not be orthogonal with respect to any inner product.

Comment: The degrees of freedom relies mainly on the weight function but also on the integration interval $[a,b]$, knowing that your polynomial $p(x)$ must be such that $\int_a^b p(x)x^{i}w(x)dx=0$ for $i=0,1,...k-1$ which represents a rather difficult-to-manage set of constraints...

Comment: Does it help if we set $[a, b] = [-1, 1]$?

Comment: 1) I wasn't aware of your comment because you hadn't used my pseudo. 2) Yes, up to a change of coordinates that you can incorporate into a new weight function, you can assume you are on this classical interval (at least for being connected with Chebyshev or Legendre polynomials).

Comment: Your phrasing is a bit ambiguous: do you mean you’re given $p$ and a weight function and want to find some orthogonal sequence, or do you mean you’re just given $p$ and want to construct the weight function as well as the orthogonal sequence?  Those are very different questions! (Be careful with this kind of phrasing in general — “given an X, can we find a Y, for some Z” is always ambiguous about whether Z is part of the given data or part of the goal.)

Comment: Thanks @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine - My question is the latter, I suspect that in most cases the former question has no answer (or, more specifically, we cannot find an orthogonal polynomial sequence with respect to the given weight function).

Comment: It's worth noting that applying Gram-Schmidt to the list $p, x^0, \ ..., \ x^{n - 1}$ is not a viable solution, as the resulting list will not respect the required degree constraint in general.

Comment: @JackCeroni: Thanks!  I strongly recommend editing that clarification into the question, then.  This is certainly the more interesting and difficult interpretation.  (For completeness: Under the other interpretation, where the inner product is specified, then the answer would be “This is possible iff $p$ is orthogonal to all of $1,x,\ldots,x^{k-1}$, and in that case, the sequence can be found by applying Gram-Schmidt to $1,x,\ldots,x^{k-1},p,x^{k+1},\ldots$.”)

Comment: Absolutely, I will edit the question for clarity, thank you for your suggestion @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine

Comment: Sounds like the question is essentially "Given $p$, find a weight function such that $p$ is orthogonal to all polynomials of lesser degree".

Comment: Yes, you're right @eyeballfrog

Comment: As a first step, if we can find polynomials $a,b,q$ such that $(ap')' + ab'p' = q p$, we would have $(a e^b p')' - q e^b p = 0$, a Sturm-Liouville equation. A weighting function could then be found by dividing up $q$ into polynomials as $q = c + \lambda d$. This is particularly simple if $q$ is a constant, though I'm not sure there's always such a choice of $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. There is [a theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106312/intersection-between-orthogonal-complement-of-a-subspace-and-a-set) stating that in $\Bbb{R}^N$ with the standard inner product, if $V$ is a subspace such that $V \cap [0,\infty)^n = \{0\}$ then its orthogonal complement is such that $V^\perp \cap (0,\infty)^n \ne \emptyset$.

Given $p(x)$ your real polynomial of degree $k$ **with $k$ simple zeros on $(-1,1)$**.

Take $1/N$ smaller than the distance between the pairs of zeros and the distance between the zeros and $\pm 1$.

For each $a\in (0,1/N)$ let $V_a$ be the subspace of $\Bbb{R}^{2N}$ generated by the $k$ vectors $(v_n)_i=(\frac{i}N+a)^n p(\frac{i}N+a)$ with $i\in -N\ldots N-1,n\in 0\ldots k-1$.

Due to the number of sign changes of a polynomial of degree $<k$, $V_a$ doesn't contain any non-zero non-negative vector.

So by the theorem $V_a^\perp$ will contain a vector $u_a$ with strictly positive entries.

$V_a^\perp$ varies continuously with $a$. So we can choose the vectors $u_a$ to be continuous in $a$.

That's it, let $w(\frac{i}N + a) = (u_a)_i$.

By construction $w$ is non-negative and it is such that $$\forall n<k, \int_{-1}^1 w(x)x^np(x)dx=\int_0^{1/N}\sum_{i=-N}^{N-1}w(\frac{i}N+a)(\frac{i}N+a)^n p(\frac{i}N+a)da=0$$

Comment: Wow, very nice, thank you!